# Java: message system needs to be able to pass various objects

Tags: java, messaging

I'm writing a messaging system to queue actions for my program to execute. I need to be able to pass various objects by the messages. I currently have a `Msg` object that accepts (`Action` enum, `Data<?>...`object). The `Data` object is intended to be a wrapper for any object I might pass.

Currently the `Data` object uses this code, with generics:

```
public class Data<T> {

    private T data;

        public Data(T data){
        this.data = data;
    }

    public T getData(){
        return data;
    }

}
```

The `Msg` object takes `Data<?>...` type, so `Msg` has a `Data<?>[]` field.

If `getData()` is called on a `Data<?>` object, it returns the `Object` type. Obviously not ideal.

I need to be able to pass, say, `Image` objects as well as `String` objects. I'm certain there's a better way of passing arbitrary data.

Comment: What do you mean by "*Unpacking a single `Data` object returns the `Object` type*"?

Comment: @null Using the `getData()` function on a `Data<?>` object returns `Object` type. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: If one data is associated to one action, then you know in advance what type you are manipulating depending on this action, so you would be able to unpack it !

Answer (score 0):

If you call getData().getClass() you will get the class or type that was passed, which doesn't seem to me to be the same as an Object. You might not know what you are getting, but you can either find out or define a common interface for everything you might pass. You could for example, call toString() or getClass() on anything passed. Your question is that you are passing any conceivable object, so my question is what are you going to do with it? If you are going to serialize it into a database you don't need know anything about what type it is, otherwise you can test it or call a common interface.

```
public class PlayData {
    class Msg {
        private List<Data<?>> message = new ArrayList<Data<?>>();
        public void addData(Data<?> datum) { message.add(datum); }
        public void printTypes() { for ( Data<?> datum: message ) { System.out.println(datum.getData().getClass()); } }
    }
    class Data<T> {
        private T value;
        public Data(T value) { this.value = value; }
        public T getData() { return value; }
    }
    class Listener {
        public void receive(Msg msg) { msg.printTypes(); }
    }
    class Sender {
        private Listener listener;
        public Sender(Listener listener) { this.listener = listener; }
        public void send(Msg msg) { listener.receive(msg); }
    }
    class MyPacket {
        int i;
        public MyPacket(int i) { this.i = i; }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { new PlayData().run(); }
    public void run() throws Exception {
        Sender sender = new Sender(new Listener());
        Msg msg = new Msg();
        msg.addData(new Data<String>("testing") );
        msg.addData(new Data<MyPacket>(new MyPacket(42)) );
        sender.send(msg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're having trouble is that you're trying to get the static typing system of Java to do something that it can't. Once you convert from a `Data<T>` to a `Data<?>`, whatever `T` was is effectively lost. There's no clean way to get it back.

The quickest way to get it to work (from what you have right now) is to start throwing casts everywhere, like this:

```
Data<?> d = new Data("Hello");
String contents = (String)d.getData();
```

This is kind of a terrible idea, so let's go back to the drawing board.

If (ideally), you have all of the types you could ever need ahead of time (i.e. every `Data` is *either* a `String` or an `Image` or an `Integer`), then you can pretty easily (though it's a bit tedious) define a *Sum type* (aka a *union* if you're coming from C) of the different types of data you'll have to handle. As a class invariant, we assume that **exactly one** of the fields is non-null, and the rest are null. For this example I'll assume it can be either a `String`, an `Image`, or an `Integer`, but it's fairly simple to add or remove types from `Data` as necessary.

```
public class Data {
    private Image imgData;
    private String stringData;
    private Integer intData;

    public Data(Image img) {
        this.imgData = img;
    }

    public Data(String stringData) {
        this.stringData = stringData;
    }

    public Data(Integer intData) {
        this.intData = intData;
    }

    public boolean isImage() {
        return imageData != null;
    }

    public boolean isInteger() {
        return intData != null;
    }

    public boolean isString() {
        return stringData != null;
    }

    public Image asImage() {
        if(! isImage()) throw new RuntimeException();
        return imgData;
    }

    public Image asString() {
        if(! isString()) throw new RuntimeException();
        return stringData;
    }

    public Image asInt() {
        if(! isInt()) throw new RuntimeException();
        return intData;
    }
}
```

One necessary side effect is that we cannot wrap `null` without causing exceptional behavior. Is this is desired, it isn't too difficult to modify the class to allow for it.

With this `Data` class, it's pretty easy to do `if-else` logic to parse it.

```
Data d = ....... //Get a data from somewhere
if(d.isImage()) {
    Image img = d.asImage();
    //...
} else if (d.isString()) {
    String string = d.asString();
    //...
} else if (d.isInteger()) {
    Integer i = d.asInt();
    //...
} else {
    throw new RuntimeException("Illegal data " + d + " received");
}
```